# REGEX: Specific Help Needed with matching DOUBLE BACKSLASH in PHP

Tags: php, regex, escaping

I'm having issues matching a double backslash pattern with a preg_match function. I understand that to literally match a backslash, you need to use 4 (`\\\\`) to match a single slash. I assumed therefor that to match a literall double slash i.e. `\\t` would be (`\\\\\\\\t`)?

This doesn't seem to recognise the pattern though within my strings?

Here's what I've got so far...

```
preg_match("/\"&?$string:?(\\\\\\\\t)?\".{1,7}$lang=\"&?(.*?):?\"/smi",$cont,$matches);
```

To explain further:

I need it to match the following...

```
"Unlock\\t Automatically ar="فتح\\t تحديث"

"&Unlock Automatically   ar="فتح\\t تحديث"

"&Unlock: Automatically  ar="فتح\\t تحديث"

"&Unlock:Something\\t Automatically   ar="فتح\\t تحديث"
```

It correctly matches the strings with ampersands and colons but not the slashes?

Any ideas everyone?

Comment: The `t` is likely to be your problem, since `\t` is a tab.

Comment: Yeh I imagined so, but I have no control of the string beings used? Is there a known workaround for this?

Comment: Btw, none of your example sentences contain a double backslash.

Comment: Look into using [`preg_quote`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) for dynamic strings used within your pattern. Be sure to specify the delimiter parameter.

Comment: No, thanks... but preg_quote doesn't do what I need :-(

Answer (score 0):

One back slash, `'\'`, is used for escaping the next symbol. So to capture a single back slash you need `'\\'`. To capture a double you need `'\\\\'`.

```
preg_match('/(\\\\)/i', 'فتح\\t تحديث', $result);
$result = Array
(
    [0] => \\
    [1] => \\
)
```

You also have a 't' in there which is escaped in itself in the string but for different reasons. So to capture all in one:

```
preg_match('/(\\\\t)/i', 'فتح\\t تحديث', $result);
$result = Array
(
    [0] => \\t
    [1] => \\t
)
```

Should be enough to get you going. Let me know if you require any further assistance.

P.S.
Here is an excellent tool to test RegEx in PHP (PCRE RegEx) - http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/